# Getting top layer of 3d noise

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I've generated a cubic world using [FastNoiseLite](https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoiseLite) but I don't know how to differentiate top level blocks as grass and bottom one's dirt when using 3d noise.

```cpp
TArray<float> CalculateNoise(const FVector& ChunkPosition)
{
    Densities.Reset();

    // ChunkSize is 32
    for (int z = 0; z < ChunkSize; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < ChunkSize; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < ChunkSize; x++)
            {
                const float Noise = GetNoise(FVector(ChunkPosition.X + x, ChunkPosition.Y + y, ChunkPosition.Z + z));
                Densities.Add(Noise - ChunkPosition.Z);
            }
        }
    }

    return Densities;
}

void AddCubeMaterial(const FVector& ChunkPosition)
{
    const int32 DensityIndex = GetIndex(ChunkPosition);
    const float Density = Densities[DensityIndex];

    if (Density < 1)
    {
        // Add Grass block
    }

    // Add dirt block
}

void GetNoise(const FVector& Position) const
{
    const float Height = 280.f;
    if (bIs3dNoise)
    {
        FastNoiseLiteObj->GetNoise(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z) * Height;
    }
    
    FastNoiseLiteObj->GetNoise(Position.X, Position.Y) * Height;
}
```

This is the result when using 3D noise.

[3D Noise result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHWdn.jpg)

But if I switch to 2D noise it works perfectly fine.

[2D Noise result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT3qz.jpg)

Comment: I am sorry that I am unable to continue to help you further, I fixed the part that I could.

Comment: @Strom No worries. I know the issue is on my side so I'll continue to make it work following your suggestions. I'm really happy you taking the time to write the code and help me out. Much appreciated. I'll mark your answer as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applies to Perlin like noise.

Your integer chunk size is dis-contiguous in noise space.

'Position'  needs to be scaled by `1/Height`. To scale the noise as a contiguous block.  Then scale by `Height`.

---

If you were happy with the XY axes(2D), you could limit the scaling to the Z axis:

```
FastNoiseLiteObj->GetNoise(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z / Height) * Height;
```

This adjustment provides a noise continuous Z block location with respect to Position(X,Y).

### Edit in response to comments

Contiguous:
The noise algorithm guarantees continuous output in all dimensions.

By sampling every 32 pixels (dis-contiguous sampling), The continuity is broken, on purpose(?) and augmented by the Density.

To guarantee a top level grass layer:

`Densities.Add(Noise + (ChunkPosition.Z > Threshold) ? 1: 0);`
Your code`- ChunkPosition.Z` made grass thicker as it went down. Add it back if you wish.

To add random overhangs/underhangs reduce the Density threshold randomly:
`if (Density < (rnd() < 0.125)? 0.5 : 1)`
I leave the definition of `rnd()` to your preferred random distribution.

To almost always have overhangs, requires forward lookup of the next and previous blocks' Z in noise.

Precalculate the noise values for the next line into alternating arrays 2 wider than the width to support the edges set at 0.

The algorithm is:

```
// declare  arrays: currentnoise[ChunkSize + 2] and nextnoise[ChunkSize +2] and alpha=.2; //see text
    for (int y = 0; y < ChunkSize; y++) // note the reorder y-z-x
    {
        // pre load currentnoise for z=0
        currentnoise[0] = 0;
        currentnoise[ChunkSize+1] = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < ChunkSize; x++)
        {
             currentnoise[x + 1] = GetNoise(FVector(ChunkPosition.X + x, ChunkPosition.Y + y, ChunkPosition.Z));
        }
        for (int z = 1; z < ChunkSize -2; z++)
        {
            nextnoise[0] = 0;
            nextnoise[ChunkSize+1] = 0;
            // load next
            for (int x = 0; x < ChunkSize; x++)
            {
                nextnoise[x + 1] = GetNoise(FVector(ChunkPosition.X + x, ChunkPosition.Y + y, ChunkPosition.Z + z+1));
            }
            // apply current with next
            for (int x = 0; x < ChunkSize; x++)
            {
                Densities.Add(currentnoise[x + 1] * .75 + nextnoise[x+2] * alpha + nextnoise[x] * alpha);
            }
            
           // move next to current in a memory safe manor:
           // it is faster to swap pointers, but this is much safer for portability
           for (int i = 1; i < ChunkSize + 1; i++)
               currentnoise[i]=nextnoise[i];
        }
        // apply last z(no next)
        for (int x = 0; x < ChunkSize; x++)
        {
            Densities.Add(currentnoise[X + 1]);
        }
    }
```

Where alpha is approximately between .025 and .25 depending on preferred fill amounts.

The 2 inner most x for loops could be streamlined into 1 loop, but left separate for readability.(it requires 2 preloads)

Comment: Thank you so much Strom. Really, I appreciate the help. Your solution fixes nearly 99% of the issue although there are some top-level blocks still rendered as dirt.

And may I know what you mean by chunk size being dis-contiguous? Because the generated world has no seams between chunks, and they all share the border proper.

Comment: Even though this method works, I'm no longer getting overhangs or anything. Would it be possible to keep this fix as well as get overhangs?

Comment: @Meinhard, I think I am still missing the grass on top concept. Are you wanting grass/dirt alternating vertically? or all grass on top to mixed grass/dirt to all dirt?

Comment: For the top level grass concept here is a picture to illustrate https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/79699-wup-n-aume-gameplay-6.jpg

See how the "top" blocks (like where the player stands and top blocks on background overhangs) are grass and below each grass there is dirt. That is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm able to do it in 2D noise as mentioned in my first post with screenshot but when using 3d noise it's not working. When I use Position.Z / height as per your suggestion it works but all 3d noise goodies are gone (overhangs for example).

Comment: @Meinhard,  You need a better shader. Minecraft used voxels. Your "overhangs" are a product of the shape of the square. Your title states it, but your code cannot be adapted to support this functionality directly.

Comment: I am sorry,  but I can not continue this answer any further.  I am glad that I got you 99% of the way. Without more code or information, it is impossible to fulfill your requirements with the context given. I can think of many ways to get the top layer of grass, and all lower layers levels dirt, but none fit your given code.